How to generate and attach PDF report to send out Email using Flask
I have this java-script to generate a PDF report and it is downloaded to a temp folder on the local machine (I have limited knowledge in java-script but this is what I understand).
function download() {
let srcwidth = document.getElementById('printArea').scrollWidth;
let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
pdf.html(document.getElementById('printArea'), {
    html2canvas: {
        scale: 600 / srcwidth
        //600 is the width of a4 page. 'a4': [595.28, 841.89]
    },
    callback: function () {
        window.open(pdf.output('bloburl'));
    }
});}

How would I use Flask framework to create a route, or anyway that I could send out an email with the PDF attachment in the email as a report.
I have done some research and I do not know how to install the "wkhtmltopdf" on the server as this is another option I have googled
I am open to any suggestion as this is the struggle I have face for a long time. My end goal is to send out the email of the "pre-define" page and attach it to the email to send out as a report, either in PDF or a screen-shot should be ok.

How can I do that, please advise.
